# Can I use NSLayoutConstraint when the NIB "Use Autolayout" is not set?

Tags: macos, autolayout

My existing Mac app uses Springs and Struts and works well, but I want to use "Auto Layout" in a single view within one of my NIBs.  I will be providing these constraints programmatically (as configuring the constraints using IB is a complete nightmare).

My question is can I set `NSLayoutConstraint` objects on my view when its contained in a NIB where "Use Autolayout" is unchecked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the short answer to this question is "Yes" you can use `NSLayoutConstraint`s even though the NIB has "Use Auto Layout" turned off.

This is my view's `awakeFromNib` method:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     _field1, @"field1",
                                     _field2, @"field2",
                                     _field3, @"field3",
                                     nil];

    // Turn off conversion of Springs and Struts into NSLayoutConstraints for all the controls
    for (NSControl *control in [viewsDictionary allValues])
    {
        [control setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    }

    NSString *hformat = @"H:|-4-[field1(>=48)]-[field2]-[field3(==field1)]-4-|";
    NSArray *hconstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:hformat
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:0
                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];

    [self addConstraints:hconstraints];

    // Vertical layout (must be done for each control separately)
    for (NSString *controlName in [viewsDictionary allKeys])
    {
        NSString *vformat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-4-[%@]", controlName];
        NSArray *vconstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vformat
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:0
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary];

        [self addConstraints:vconstraints];
    }
}


    // Other init
}
```

Some notes:

- There were far more fields than shown above; I have simplified the code for posting here.
- The view in question was within a split view and in order to allow it to be resized correctly when the superview resized, I did **not** call `[self setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];`
- You need to stop the translation of Springs and Struts for all the subviews being constrained using Auto Layout.
- There was a scroll view in the *other* split view pane and I had to call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` on that scroll view otherwise an exception was raised.